# Add interval from initial time calculator [C++]

Tags: c++, if-statement, time, calculator

I'm trying to create a program that can add interval to an initial time and calculate the final time. So when I input in 7:30 and 5:30 in the 2nd round of input, it will calculate 15:00 in the final. But the code doesn't work and immediately ends with blanks after the 2 rounds of input for the two times.I think it could be how my if else statements are constructed but I don't know the correct structure for this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int hour1, hour2;
int minute1, minute2;
int second1, second2;
int finalhour, finalminute, finalsecond;
int hourfinal, minutefinal, secondfinal;

int main()
{

  cout << "Input initial hour(s), minute(s), and second(s): \n";
  cin >> hour1;

  cout << "";
  cin >> minute1;

  cout << "";
  cin >> second1;

  cout << "Input initial hour(s), minute(s), and second(s): \n";
  cin >> hour2;

  cout << "";
  cin >> minute2;

  cout << "";
  cin >> second2;
  
  finalhour = hour1+hour2;
  finalminute = minute1+minute2;
  finalsecond = second1+second2;
  
 //This code block is for hours
  if (finalhour < 24)
  {
        cout << finalhour + ":";
  }
  
  else
  {
         hourfinal = finalhour - 24;
      
         cout << hourfinal + ":";
  }
  //This code block is for minutes
  if (finalminute < 60)
  {
        cout << finalminute + ":";
  }
  
  else
  {
        minutefinal = finalminute - 60;
      
        cout << minutefinal + ":";
  }
  
  //This code block is for seconds
  if (finalsecond < 60)
  {
        cout << finalsecond + ":";
  }
  
  else
  {
        secondfinal = finalsecond - 60;
      
        cout << secondfinal + ":";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: There are multiple bugs in the shown code, flawed input processing is just one of them. `>>` expects all input to be delimited by whitespace characters, and not `:`. Entering `:` results in an error. Does your C++ textbook explain how `>>` works, and what to do to be able to handle other input formats? And once you fix the input problem, you'll discover that entering the times of 1:59:00 and 2:00:00 results in an interval of one hour and one minute, instead of one hour; this logical flaw will be the next one to fix, and the same logical flaw affects the seconds calculations too.

Comment: If you are typing `7:30` it certainly won't work.  That us not what the code you wrote expects. It's instead expecting 3 numbers for each time separated by whitespace. It does not care if the numbers are in valid range or not.

Comment: @drescherjm no, I only input 730. I don't add the colon

Comment: Typing 730 input entirely into the hour1 variable.